# SelectOption returning value in debug but not on vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectlist

I am working with visualforce and trying to set up SelectOption over the records fetched through a SOQL query. I want to populate the records in a field to a DropDown List in my VF page.

While using System.debug, results are as desired but vf page is not showing the result. Unable to understand the problem with the code

```
<apex:page Controller="PermissionSetCtrl">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >

            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:pageBlockTable var="st" value="{!qry}">         
                    <apex:column headervalue="Profile" >        
                        <apex:outputText value="{!st.Profile.Name}"/>        
                    </apex:column>         
                    <apex:column > 
                        <apex:selectList value="{!objSelected}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!Objectlist}" />
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>

                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listobj}" var="a1">
                    <apex:column headerValue="sObject" value="{!a1.SobjectType}"></apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>    

        </apex:pageBlock>    
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

And the Controller to the vf Page:

```
public class PermissionSetCtrl {
    public List<PermissionSet> qry {get; set;}
    Public List<SelectOption> Objectlist {get; set;}
    public List<ObjectPermissions> listobj {get; set;}
    public String objSelected {get; set;}

    Public List<SelectOption> getObjectlist(){
        system.debug('getObjectlist called!');
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        for(ObjectPermissions lst : listobj){
            options.add(new SelectOption(lst.SobjectType, lst.SobjectType));
        }
        System.debug(options);
        return options;
    } 

    public PermissionSetCtrl(){
        system.debug('constructor called!');
        List<string> objlist = new List<String>();
        qry = [SELECT Id, Profile.Name,(Select SObjectType from ObjectPerms) from PermissionSet WHERE Id IN (SELECT ParentId FROM ObjectPermissions WHERE SObjectType = 'Account' AND PermissionsRead = true) limit 5];                            
        for(PermissionSet s : qry){
            listobj = s.ObjectPerms;          
        }
        getObjectlist();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of issues with your code. I doubt if it compiles at all. Here are some guidelines about how you should use `{get;set;}`.

1. `{get;set;}` are invoked automatically when VF page is loaded. It means you don't need to call `getObjectList()` from constructor.
2. If you want to assign any value to any variable either initialize it in constructor otherwise use `{get;set;}`. Use both of them should be avoided.

Refer below sample for using `selectOptions`

**VF Code:**

```
<apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!objSelected}" title="Choose a object">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Objectlist}"/>
</apex:selectCheckboxes>
```

**Apex Controller**

```
public class ControllerConstructor {
    String[] objSelected = new objSelected[]{};
    public ControllerConstructor() {

    }

    public List<SelectOption> getObjectlist() {
        List<PermissionSet> lstPer = [SELECT Id, Profile.Name,(Select SObjectType from ObjectPerms) from PermissionSet WHERE Id IN (SELECT ParentId FROM ObjectPermissions WHERE SObjectType = 'Account' AND PermissionsRead = true) limit 5];
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        for(PermissionSet ps : lstPer) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(ps.Id,ps.Profile.Name));
        }
        return options;
    }

    public String[] getobjSelected() {
        return objSelected;
    }

    public void setobjSelected(String[] objSelected) {
        this.objSelected = objSelected;
    }
}
```

Above code is not tested but I guess it will give some idea about how it should be.
For detailed documentation refer this [selectOptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectOptions.htm) provided by salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Very true.. As Rohit said you have to avoid one of this -

```
 Public List<SelectOption> Objectlist {get; set;}
```

And

```
Public List<SelectOption> getObjectlist(){}
```